# AWS CodeDeploy w. Bitbucket suddenly stopped working

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I have experienced the "yesterday it was working" syndrome. I've done several minor changes which should not have resulted in such a disaster. I have no idea what is wrong, so any suggestion is welcome.

I've integrated the Bitbucket account with CodeDeploy successfully and I've done several successful deployments from a branch. Yesterday I've installed Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK and I've done a snapshot of the EC2 instance. After the server was up again I've done another successful deployment. Today I've deleted the branch I've used to deploy w. CodeDeploy and created another with the same code. Now the deployment doesn't work and there is no failure message. CodeDeploy shows no new deployments and no new archives are up in the S3 bucket. Bitbucket always shows 0 of 1 deployments passed and a timer (meaning it's still not processed). I've deleted the files in deployment-root just in case. I've even reestablished the connection in Bitbucket Settings, but nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days it is working again as usual without me having to do anything. I'm not sure what is the exact reason for this behavior, but I guess it has something to do with the slow way of operation of Bitbucket...